# System Not Booting - Failed to activate swap /swapfile

Tags: boot, partitioning, 20.04

I am 100% new to Linux as of yesterday and I seem to have done something wrong. I had the system up and running last night with no obvious issues but today when I try to boot up I get an error and the whole thing fails.

Some background: My computer has a 500 GB SSD which is what Ubuntu (version 20.04.1) was installed onto and a 2TB HDD which I formatted for use last night. I suspect that my issue is related to that fact, because I was able to restart the system multiple times without issue before I formatted it. Unfortunately I do not know enough about Ubuntu to even know where to start, and I could not seem to find any help for my specific situation online.

On startup I'm presented with 3 options

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for ubuntu
- UEFI Firmware Settings

Here's the specific output I'm getting after selecting Ubuntu:

```
    [Failed] Failed to activate swap /swapfile
    [Depend] Dependency failed for Swap
```

Let me know if there's any other information that's relevant to the issue or if there's anything I should try. All advice is appreciated.

Here is the output from running the recommended commands in the root access:

```
    grep -i swap /etc/fstab
    /swapfile          none          swap    sw          0     0

    ls -al /swapfile
    -rw------- 1 root root 2147483648 Sep 24 03:41 /swapfile
```

Comment: It appears there may be a problem with your `/etc/fstab` file which is a simple text file but contains crucial information about the partitions on your system. Some information about your disk setup would be useful. If you can boot a live USB and look at the partition layout using `gparted`, that would be great info to edit into your question, along with the contents of `fstab`.

Comment: From the GRUB menu, choose **Advanced Options**, then **Recovery Mode**, then **Root Access**. Then type `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `ls -al /swapfile`. Edit your question with that output. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for the reply. I ran the commands and attached the output.

Comment: Please see my answer, and let's see if we can get you going without too much effort. Report back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That all looks normal, but let's recreate the /swapfile.

Boot to Recovery Mode like you just did, and do this...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal` (or root # prompt)...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm nnG RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #1:**

/etc/fstab was messed up and causing the file system to be read-only. Only had 1 hour on freshly installed Ubuntu, so I recommended to reinstall Ubuntu again.

```
UUID="fae3ba3a-abaf-4eca-8139-40d5328d017c" /srv ext4 errors=remount-ro 0
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. The first two commands ran fine, but the dd command returned the error "dd: failed to open '/swapfile': Read-only file system"

Comment: Yes, manually. I don't have an easy way to copy them

Comment: sudo dd if=/dev/zero if=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

Comment: Wait I had a typo. I fixed it and now it's going crazy

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. I did have if on the first one and of on the second

Comment: The way I actually typed it in the root was 
"sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096" Sorry for the confusion

Comment: That looks better. If you type that exactly, do you still get a read-only file system?

Comment: Yes, that is what created the error

Comment: Show me `ls -al /swapfile`

Comment: -rw------- 1 root root 2147483648 Sep 24 03:41 /swapfile

Comment: The first two commands must have errored out, 'cause the /swapfile still shows the old file...

Comment: Reboot, and start over. Get back to me when you can. But don't make this too long, as I can't devote too much more time to this.

Comment: rm: cannot remove '/swapfile': Read-only file system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113389/discussion-between-heynnema-and-jordan-lejman).

Comment: This worked for me. Thank You so much. I was stuck and completely lost

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it successfully.

The biggest problem is *Read-only file system*.
As you have mentioned that /etc/fstab was messed up and causing the file system to be read-only.
I think you mount the default disk device(which the file system is installed on) wrongly in /etc/fstab.

As a solution, you only need to remount the default disk manually using uuid label in recovery mode.
Here is the command:

> sudo mount -o remount UUID=the-uuid-of-your-default-disk /

The last / means the root node.

After that, your file system is writable.
And you should revise the /etc/fstab correctly before you reboot your system.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually had a similar issue. The downside is that I completed a copy from a failed hard drive then Ubuntu decided to complete a small change to my swap. Since my config was not setup properly, everything just broke with the exact same problem.

I solved it in a different way.

So, I followed the same steps as https://askubuntu.com/a/1277621/1168565 from Heynnema and worked wonders but, in my issue, that wasn't the root problem.

In fstab, I had an issue that my root drive wasn't setup (as per normal Ubuntu installation, can be explained later). So, when I added my main hard drive to fstab as `/`, I was able to boot with no issue.

Here's an example of my fstab:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=fa1b78f3-9d98-42e3-9a72-a9716000d8f9 /               ext4 defaults 0 0
/swapfile       none     swap   sw   0   0
UUID=b31e2ef4-6240-47d6-8ef9-2b98622603a8 /1tb       ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=e37a2ae4-74c8-4bd1-b3ad-36ba5904a680 /500gb     ext4 defaults 0 0
```

So, my line 3 didn't exist before and caused issues since the swap couldn't find `/` when it was initializing after the update.

But, when I loaded into the recovery system, I was unable to edit fstab since it was in readonly. Simply use the command `mount -o remount /` and the system will automatically remove the readonly for you to update the `/etc/fstab` using your preferred text editor.

If your system is having issues or locked you out due to the readonly issue, I would suggest a livecd system to modify your `/etc/fstab`, then boot normally.