# Getting error - failed to active swap /swapfile

Tags: boot, 22.04, swap, acpi

I'm new to **Ubuntu desktop** from Windows, installed it yesterday. It was working fine, except ACPI error. But today I'm getting error while booting my machine.

```
[ 0.274572] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCIO.GPP2.BCM5], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
[ 0.274580] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/ps
/dev/sda2: clean, 449907/61022208 files, 9220737/244059136 blocks
[FAILED] Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swaps.
[FAILED] Failed to start Userspace Out-Of-Memory (00M) Killer.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
[FAILED] Failed to start Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer.
[ 11.659491] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (202
[ 11.659550] ACPI Error: Aborting method HWMC due to previous error (AE_AML_O
[ 11.659571] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WMAA due to previous error
[ 11.685486] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (202
[ 11.685547] ACPI Error: Aborting method HWMC due to previous error (AE_AML_O
[ 11.685571] ACPI Error: Aborting method_SB.WMID.WMAA due to previous error
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
```

/etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

blkid

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="3554c80c-3021-48ef-b6c2-cd4a7f2ef468" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9f17a076-e829-4e4f-be84-620be099dd9f"
/dev/sda1: UUID="0535-3488" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="48f08ef9-73e2-4c60-862c-77519bdf4dba"
```

```
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS

sda
sda1 vfat   FAT32       0535-34B8
sda2 ext4   1.0         3554c80c-3021-48ef-b6c2-cd4a7f2ef468 849.3G  2%     /
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: Can you Check your Harddisk from a live Session with smartmontools? And after that start up with an older Kernel If one is present in your Install.

Answer (score 0):

### /etc/fstab

sudo pico /etc/fstab 
there 2 lines were missing 
`/dev/sda2   /  ext4   errors=remount-ro  0  1` 
and 
`/dev/sda1   /boot/efi  vfat  defaults   0   1`

Answer (score -1):

The ACPI (your powermanagement) errors happen on all of my machines - nothing to worry about.

Your problem is:

> [FAILED] Failed to start Userspace Out-Of-Memory (00M) Killer

**Corrected answer**:

The “OOM Killer” or “Out of Memory Killer” is a process that the Linux kernel employs when the system is critically low on memory. This situation occurs because processes on your device are consuming a large amount of memory, and the system requires more memory for its own processes and to allocate to other processes.

As Jos pointed out it is not the disk space, but the memory that is missing. To fix this you might have to disable some services which are using that memory. The command `free` will show, how much memory is used in the system.

Concerning the swap problem. Someone [asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277616/system-not-booting-failed-to-activate-swap-swapfile) this before, maybe your harddisk is readOnly (which will prevent creating any files)

Comment: Statistics shown in the question indicate that usage of the root partition is 2%.

Comment: I did this (https://devicetests.com/managing-massive-var-log-folder-ubuntu), but how to fix ```failed to active swap /swapfile``` error?

Comment: See my revised answer. I didn't read your question correctly.