# Kubunutu Booting into emergency mode 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: partitioning, mount, kubuntu, swap

I've recently made the switch over to kubuntu on main system from windows.

Downloaded steam and most of games. Set a new partition on secondary nvme (/dev/nvme1n1). On the primary /dev/nvme0n1 set a swap of 31 GiB

I am booting into emergency mode after restarting the system. Was able to access the partition and play games until I restarted.

Mounted nvme1n1 to newly created folder in home. /home/twobeesan/GAMES/
All partitions were set to ext4

Journal shows these errors:

swapfile.swap: Failed with result 'exit-code

Failed to activate swap /swapfile.

TwoBeeSan-Desktop kernel: EXT4-fs (nvme1n1p1): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities

TwoBeeSan-Desktop systemd[1] : home-twobeesan-Games.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code

Please let me know if I can provide any extra info. Loving it but clearly doing something wrong lol  Thank you.

Comment: See this answer for how to deal with emergency mode: https://askubuntu.com/a/1470673/243321

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System Not Booting - Failed to activate swap /swapfile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277616/system-not-booting-failed-to-activate-swap-swapfile)